# Probability problem involving geometric distribution and expected value

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, expectation

We're given the following problem:

"An experiment is conducted until it results in success: the first step has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ to be successful, the second step (only conducted if the first step had no success) has probability $\frac{1}{3}$ to be successful, the third step (only conducted if the first two steps had no success) has probability $\frac{1}{4}$ to be successful : if none of the steps were successful, we repeat the experiment until success is achieved. Assuming the first step has cost $2$, and the second step as well as the third step have cost $1$, what is the overall cost until success ? "

Here's my approach. Let $X$ be the random variable the counts the number of steps required to achieve success. Thus giving me: $$P(X=1) = \frac{1}{2} \\ P(X=2)=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6} \\ P(X=3) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{48}  $$

Now, to compute the expected cost, I did the following: $$E(X) = 2 \cdot 1 \cdot P(X=1) + 1 \cdot 2 \cdot P(X=2) + 1 \cdot 3 \ P(X=3)$$ (where the first coeffeicient of each term of the sum is the cost of each step). This gave me $\frac{79}{48}$ , which is far from the correct answer.

So, I do not understand what I did wrong (I guess there must be a problem with my reasoning), and I do not know how to find the correct result (which is $\frac{34}{9}$).

Comment: Why does your sum terminate?  Presumably we are meant to continue this as long as necessary, with step $n$ costing $\frac 1{n+1}$.  Either that or you repeat, starting from step $1$ (the problem isn't clear on what happens if you fail all three steps).

Comment: Also, where does $\frac 56$ come from?  To get to step $3$ I need both of the first two to fail, that's $\frac 12\times \frac 23=\frac 13$.

Comment: And, where are you getting your costs?  If I win on the first step it costs me $2$.  If I win on the second it costs me $2+1=3$.  If I win on the third it costs me $2+1+1=4$.

Comment: @lulu I do not understand how you find  that to get to step 3, you have to do $1/2 \cdot 2/3$ . Where does the $2/3$ come from ? Because the way I understood this, is that to get to step 3, you must first fail the first step (which expalains where $1/2$ comes from) and then fail again at the second step (i.e $5/6$). I'm sure you're right, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You fail step $1$ with probability $\frac 12$.  You then fail step $2$ with probability $\frac 23=1-\frac 13$.  To fail both then has probability $\frac 12\times \frac 23=\frac 13$.

Comment: Work it out with a numerical example.  Say you start with $3000$ cases.  Of these, $1500$ fail the first step.  Of those $1500$, $1000$ also fail the second step.  Thus $1000$ fail both and that's $\frac 13$ of what you started with.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry but I still do not get it. Why is it not: $P(X=3) = (1-P(X=1) ) \cdot (1-P(X=2)) \cdot \frac{1}{4}$. Because from what I've understood of what you said, you do: $P(X=3) = P(\mathrm{no successatfirststep}) \cdot P(\mathrm{nosuccessatsecondstep}) \cdot P(\mathrm{successat thethirdstep})$.

Comment: The problem is that $\left(1-P(X=2) \right)$  includes all the instances when you succeeded at the first step.  Seriously, try it with the numerical example for clarity.

Comment: I got it, after a while, but I finally did. Thank you

Comment: I imagined it like this: $P(X=2)= P\textbf{(}$fail at step 1 AND succeed at step 2$\textbf{)}$, thus $1-P(X=2) = P\textbf{(}$ succeed at step 1 OR fail at step 2$\textbf{)}$, applying De Morgan's Laws. Which explains why $1-P(X=2)$ includes all the instances when you succeeded at the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my reading of the question (though I can see where you may have interpreted differently), your random variable $X$ can take on values greater than $3$. If all 3 first steps fail, we precede to a 4th step which is a repetition of the first step. Thus, e.g., if $X=4$, the cost will be $2+1+1+2=6$. You must take into account that $X$ can be any natural number.

To fix this, let $Y$ be the cost, and take your equation 
$$E(Y) = 2 \cdot 1 \cdot P(X=1) + 1 \cdot 2 \cdot P(X=2) + 1 \cdot 3 \ P(X=3)$$
and modify it to 
$$E(Y) = 2 \cdot P(X=1) + 3 \cdot P(X=2) + 4 \cdot \ P(X=3) + q(4+E(Y))$$
where $q = \frac12\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac34$ is the probability of failure on all three steps, and the $(4+E(Y))$ comes from the fact that if we fail the three steps, we are back where we started, plus we have already spent a cost of $4$. (I have also modified the coefficients as per lulu's comment.)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mu_{0}$ denote the expectation of the cost of the steps yet
to be done if no steps have been made.

Let $\mu_{1}$ denote the expectation of the cost of the steps yet
to be done if step 1 has been made without success.

Let $\mu_{2}$ denote the expectation of the cost of the steps yet
to be done if step 1 and step 2 have been made without success.

Then we have the following equalities.

$\mu_{0}=\frac{1}{2}2+\frac{1}{2}\left[2+\mu_{1}\right]=2+\frac{1}{2}\mu_{1}$

$\mu_{1}=\frac{1}{3}1+\frac{2}{3}\left[1+\mu_{2}\right]=1+\frac{2}{3}\mu_{2}$

$\mu_{2}=\frac{1}{4}1+\frac{3}{4}\left[1+\mu_{0}\right]=1+\frac{3}{4}\mu_{0}$

Then:$$\mu_0=2+\frac12\left[1+\frac23\left[1+\frac34\mu_0\right]\right]$$

The solution of this equality is: $$\mu_0=\frac{34}9$$